# Disable Free Shipping when shipping is enclosed with multiple products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to exclude free shipping when I have another shipping option in my cart.

Each painting (on the paintings page) has 3 options, only one option has shipping. If multiple paintings are purchased and at least one has shipping, I don't want free shipping to be an option.

Example:

> Painting1: Qty 1 $15 shipping
>   Painting2: Qty 1 $0 shipping
>
> **Shipping Options**
>   Total Shipping: $15
>   Local Pickup

This is the site I need help with: http://philvassilart.com/

Comment: In a nutshell, If there only one product in the cart than you wish to  take shipping charges. If product is more than one than customer will not required to pay for shipping. Is that what you want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to clarify what you're asking for help with. You should show the code that you have so far and explain what you're having trouble solving. Good luck!

Comment: @Aki It depends on the product, every "product" has 3 options, only one of those options has shipping.  if the total cart has shipping I do not want a free shipping. IF the cart has no shipping, i want the free shipping option.